# Where are operators defined (in C#)?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, operators

Just wondering where the rules for operators in C# are actually defined.

E.g. where can I see the code which says that == checks the references of two objects?

I can see the operator overloads in e.g. the String class but now i'm interested in seeing the 'base' case. Is it just something that the compiler explicitly knows what to do with and therefore there is no code which we can view using tools such as Reflector.

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if most operators couldn't be defined in the language itself (in most languages, actually).

Comment: @delnan: of course, with either only using NOT AND (NAND) or only using NOT OR (NOR) you could define any other operator, so you can build a language with only one of these operators predefined outside the language. In fact, this is how microchips work.

Comment: That's why I said *most*. The logical operators can be reduced to either NAND or NOR. But how is e.g. `+` defined?

Comment: @delnan: the same way as in chips? ORing and ANDing them, bit by bit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't see it in code (except *maybe* in the [SSCLI](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en), I haven't checked).

You'll need to look at the [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E). For example:

> **7.10.6 Reference type equality operators**
>
> The predefined reference type equality
>   operators are:
>
> ```
> bool operator ==(object x, object y);
> bool operator !=(object x, object y);
> ```
>
> The operators return the result of
>   comparing the two references for
>   equality or non-equality.
>
> Since the predefined reference type
>   equality operators accept operands of
>   type `object`, they apply to all types
>   that do not declare applicable
>   operator `==` and operator `!=`
>   members. Conversely, any applicable
>   user-defined equality operators
>   effectively hide the predefined
>   reference type equality operators.

Answer (score 6):

The `==` operator compiles down to a call to the `ceq` [IL instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions).

Comment: For most, but not for all. E.g. `string`, E.g. `System.Type`